# Email-based CI server

Tags: open-source, software-development, continuous-integration, mailing-list

I'm looking for a CI-style service capable of running "gatekeeping" tasks on patches being sent via email. I'm picturing something like the following:

1. Send email to internal mail server (e.g. `internal-review-projectX@example.com`)
2. Some process captures mail to said address and runs a set of tasks
3. If all tasks pass, the original mail gets sent to a destination address (e.g. `dev@acmeopensourceproject.com`) **from the original sender**
4. If any task fails, the mail is not sent and the original sender is notified

I'm aware that mail servers can be configured to run tasks like virus scans. However, I'd like to keep this separate from the main mail server.

Does such a tool exist?

Comment: What you are describing doesn't seem very hard to do. I'm a Procmail person myself but these days I guess you should look at Maildrop. But why would you send on the original patch email at all? If the build succeeds, commit it in a new branch and push that instead (or as well?). Conversely, feedback to the sender if the build fails would seem useful.